# What is it called when a letter is within another letter?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology, typography

What is it called when a letter is within another letter? For example, the letter O within the letter L:

[image: Example 1]

**Edit:** Or the first C in the Coca-Cola logo:

[image: Example 2]

Does this arrangement of type have a name?

Comment: This is probably a drop capital, as tchrist notes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for may be ***kerning***, but it isn’t quite clear from so small a sample. I can’t tell whether that is just a **superscripted** *o* or a **drop capital** *L* and a regular *o*, but in either case the *o* is **kerned**  into the space of the *L*.

So I would look up both [***drop capitals***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial) and [***kerning***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning), and see whether some combination of those ideas answers your question.

---

**Edit**: Your logo example is definitely an example of aggressive kerning.  Consider these two examples, the first tightly kerned, the second not so:

[image: tomorrow kerning example]

Notice how the second one above now actually looks wrong, as though it had spurious spaces in it; it’s like [this *xkcd* lesson](http://xkcd.com/1015/):

[image: XKCD on kerning]

In extreme cases,  aggressive kerning can in many cases become actual ligatures; notice all the letters here that actually touch:

[image: litterae d’oeuvre]

Or they can so tighten up with a combination of special kerning and even an occasional ligature so to become a sort of stylized symbol:

[image: stylized symbols]

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't show a [kerned drop cap](http://i.stack.imgur.com/z6r6G.png) though.

Comment: I believe it may be a more extreme version of kerning. I wonder if there is a different word for it in this case. I will update my question with another example.

Comment: It's not clear to me that this is necessarily kerning. If it's a regular L with a superscripted o that have been fused into *one symbol*, it seems unfair to call it kerning - much like the mathematical symbol ±, or the digraph æ, or the ligature ĳ, or the numero sign №.

Comment: +1: This is most likely a drop-cap with kerning.

Comment: @Billy His first sample is just too small to know what he’s really looking for, but the Coke example suggests it is just heavy, very stylized kerning.

Comment: +1 for xkcd and very detailed example. I think you're probably right with "aggressive kerning", but I'll hold off accepting the answer for a little bit, if you don't mind, to see if anybody knows if there is a specific word for it.

Comment: A friend of mine calls them [lettrines](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lettrine) purely for comic effect.

Answer (score 3):

The first is a case of *kerned drop cap*.

The second is apparently an artwork (custom) and not a typographic symbol.

Trademarks, especially, are custom designed artwork that can be **purposely** different from standard typography.

The two do not fit into a single class.

Answer (score 2):

How about a [ligature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature)? This looks close to what you want.

Comment: That is not a ligature. Two letters must be bound together to form a ligature, like **æ**.

Comment: @Robusto: The page I linked to gives many examples of ligatures, some not physically joined (e.g. the 'broken U', the Unicode 'ij' and 'fi' and 'fl', the letter it calls the "uo-ligature" ů, and the Chinese character ligatures). Ligatures *in English* (and indeed Latin) are all physically joined, yes, but that wasn't the question. The Dutch 'ij', for example, is very definitely one glyph: at the start of a sentence or proper noun it appears as 'IJ', rather than 'Ij'.

Comment: @Billy The page you cite doesn’t know what it’s talking about: “The tilde diacritic as used in Spanish and Portuguese, now representing the palatal nasal sound in the letter ñ and nasalization of the affected vowel, respectively, originated as an nn ligature (Espanna = España, anno = año). Similarly, the circumflex in French spelling stems from the ligature of a silent s.”  **WRONG!**  A diacritic is not a ligature.